# How can I preload fonts on wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress, pagespeed, preload, lighthouse

Running Pagespeed on a wordpress i'm working on it says 4.5sec are taken by this resource: **/wp-content/themes/dt-the7/fonts/icomoon-the7-microwidgets-16x16/fonts/icomoon-the7-microwidgets-16x16.ttf?dqeoeo**

and it suggests to use preload for it.

So I tried to add this to the header-single.php in wordpress before `</head>`:

```
<link rel="preload" href="/wp-content/themes/dt-the7/fonts/icomoon-the7-microwidgets-16x16/fonts/icomoon-the7-microwidgets-16x16.ttf?dqeoeo" as="font" type="font/ttf" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

but without any result. Does someone know how I can preload such content on a wordpress?

Comment: Check in `header.php` where the `<head>` of the outputted document should be, the preload link should go in there. Also try removing the query (`?dqeoeo`) on the href value.

Comment: From what I know and see the <head></head> part is in the header-single.php not the header.php, am I wrong? It's where I sometimes placed google fonts link or other links at least. I also tried to remove that query but no results..

Comment: Solved, I forgot to put a "/" to close the html tag ..

Answer (score 1):

I face same problem when trying to improve speed for mobile.Try that way but that is not working for me. then writte code for preload. this is work for me. First go to function.php in your theme...Note Must create your theme child.

```html
add_action('wp_head' , function(){
    echo'
    <link rel="preload" href="font Url" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorgin>
    ';
});
```